# Regular expression to remove HTML tags doesn't match

Tags: java, regex

I have a String like `<li><font color='#008000'> [INFO]a random user.` and I want to eliminate html tags such as `<li>` and `<font>` from this String.

I tried to achieve this with `String.replaceAll` method in Java but it doesn't work...

```
public static String removeHTMLTags(String original){
    String str = original.replaceAll("^<.+>$", "");
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Where are the HTML tags in the String?

Comment: @Reddy Sorry, the website will resolve HTML tags...now I've added a dot prior to each tag.

Comment: Try excluding the ^ and $ because you don't want to only capture the case where the whole line is a HTML tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex isn't finding a match because the `^` and `$` anchors specify that the very first character in the input string must be `<` and the very last must be `>`.
Without those anchors, your regex still won't do what you want, however, because quantifiers (such as `.+`) are by default *greedy*.
So if your input string was `text1 <a href=foo>bar</a> text2`, your transformed output would be `text1  text2`, because the regex would match everything from the *first* `<` to the *last* `>`.
So in order to stop at the *first* `>`, you should make your quantifier non-greedy: `.+?`.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the ^ and $ and use a reluctant quantifier with the dotall flag (so dot matches newlines too):

```
public static String removeHTMLTags(String original){
    return original.replaceAll("(?s)<.+?>", "");
}
```

or use a negated character class (which will match newlines)

```
public static String removeHTMLTags(String original){
    return original.replaceAll("<[^>]+>", "");
}
```

Comment: May I know what ?s means?

Comment: `(?s)` turns on the "dotall" flag, which changes dot `.` to *also* match newlines characters (without the flag, the dot `.` matches every character *except* newline chars)

Answer (score 0):

You're transforming a HTML string that might have newline characters as well. DOT doesn't match new line characters in regex. You need to use `(?s)` (DOTALL) flag with lazy quantifier and without anchors:

```
String str = original.replaceAll("(?s)<.+?>", "");
```

Though I must caution you using regex to parse/transform HTML, it can be error prone.